# Redis backend not working?

Tags: python, django, redis, celery

I'm using Celery with redis in my django project. I'm trying to call the expire function with a delay of 10 seconds from my celery_app. Whenever the function executes, the page just says localhost did not respond. I assume its because my backend is not working?  Can anyone please help? 
P.S. the get method works if I remove the 2 lines with result

**celery_app.py**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
import os
from celery import Celery

from django.conf import settings
from celery.schedules import crontab

# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'IrisOnline.settings')

app = Celery('IrisOnline', broker='redis://localhost:6379/0',backend="redis://localhost:6379/0",include=[
    "IrisOnline.tasks",
    "order_management.tasks"
])

app.conf.update(
    task_serializer='json',
    accept_content=['json'],
    result_serializer='json',
    timezone='Asia/Manila',
)
app.conf.beat_schedule = {
    'add-every-30-seconds': {
        'task': 'IrisOnline.tasks.printthis',
        'schedule':(crontab(hour=13,minute=33)),
    },
}

app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')

app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)

@app.task(name="expire")
def expire():
    print("object expired")
```

views.py

```
def get(request):

    if "approved_cart" not in request.session or not request.session["approved_cart"]:
        return redirect("/checkout/cart/")

    cart = request.session["cart"]
    customer = Customer.objects.get(user=request.user)
    order = Order.objects.create(customer=customer)

    result = expire.apply_async(countdown=40) #these causes the errors
    result.get()


    for product_id, quantity in cart.items():
        # Deduct from inventory
        product = Product.objects.get(id=product_id)
        product.quantity -= quantity
        product.save()

        # Add quantity to order
        OrderLineItems.objects.create(
            product=Product.objects.get(id=product_id),
            quantity=quantity,
            parent_order=order
        )

    request.session["cart"] = {}  # Empty cart
    request.session["approved_cart"] = False
    request.session.modified = True
    context = make_context(request)
    context["total_price"] = order.total_price

    return render(request, 'purchase.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call `result.get()` this actually waits for the task to complete - see the [Celery documentation](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.result.html#celery.result.AsyncResult.get).

So in your case this will, at best, wait for 40 seconds as you have set `countdown=40`. I think most browsers wait more than 40 seconds for a timeout, so this may not be your issue.

However you should really ask yourself: why are you running a separate task if you're going to wait for it's result within the code that initiated that task?

Coming back to your problem - the error suggests your separate task is not running. One way to debug this is to set `CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER = True` in your settings. This makes the task run right away in the calling process. If the code works in those conditions, then the problem is likely that your celery workers are not running.

Comment: Hello, thanks for responding. When I run my worker the function executes every 40 seconds? This is very weird. The function runs but localhost doesnt respond and doesnt give me the next page

Comment: I tried CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER and it works now apparently but it doesnt execute after 40 seconds

Comment: Yes, `CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER` means the code will run straight away - it's mostly used for debugging. The fact it works that way means your issue is either that your worker thread isn't running, or that the 40 second timeout is too long. You can remove the `CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER` and try removing `result.get()` from your code - the task will still execute in 40 seconds, but your caller process won't hang waiting for it. If it works that way, then your celery workers are running - if it doesn't work, then probably you need to check your workers.